# How to handle a url encoded by utf-8 in webpy?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, web.py

> utf-8:%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD ([**Translate**](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD))

The above word meaning 'Hello' in Chinese and ecoded by utf-8

I want to pass it as a parameter in url such as "example.com/query=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD"

But I got 404 in response,while "example.com/query=Hello" works well

I just display the parameter in the web page.

Can someone help me?

Solved: Sorry,I write the wrong regular expression... Should I delete this quesiton?

Comment: I'm glad you resolved it. Yes, delete this question

Answer (score 0):

```
In [20]: 'http://www.google.com/search?%s' % (urllib.urlencode({'q':'python'}))
Out[20]: 'http://www.google.com/search?q=python'
```